# Hastening URL decoding process in R

Tags: r, text-processing

I am working in R and I am trying to make the function below computationally faster. I am trying to decode UTF-8 encoded URLs. Currently, we look for the characters in the raw URL, x, that have percentages. These percentages are special characters of the form "%56", and need to be transformed accordingly.

I believe that our function runs slower than expected because of how we save each bit. Currently, I create a vector of lists with out in order to store all of our text, special characters or not. This allows me to store characters of different lengths at a computational price. In our last step, we concatenate all of our lists to get a character output. I believe there is a faster way to store and output our data because concatenation is a lengthy and computationally expensive process. Please assist in any way possible!

This is a modified version of the utils::URLdecode function. It currently works, but it runs slow on large amounts of text.

```
function(URL) {
  vapply(URL, function(URL) {
    x <- charToRaw(URL)
    pc <- charToRaw("%")
    out <- vector("list", length(x))  # Preallocate a list for storing values
    i <- 1L
    pc_indices <- which(x == pc)  # Find the indices of '%' in 'x' at the start
    pc_count <- length(pc_indices)  # Number of '%' occurrences
    
    while (i <= length(x)) {
      if (i %in% pc_indices) {  # Check if current index is a '%'
        y <- as.integer(x[(i + 1L):(i + 2L)])  # Extract the next two elements
        y[y > 96L] <- y[y > 96L] - 32L
        y[y > 57L] <- y[y > 57L] - 7L
        y <- sum((y - 48L) * c(16L, 1L))
        out[[i]] <- as.raw(as.character(y))  # Insert value into 'out'
        i <- i + 3L
      } else {
        out[[i]] <- x[i]  # Insert value into 'out'
        i <- i + 1L
      }
    }
    
    rawToChar(do.call(c, out))
  }, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and sample output?

Comment: I imagine some kind of regex lookahead would be faster than a while loop, but it's hard to say without access to example inputs